# How to print multiple WPF pages in one document

Tags: wpf, vb.net, printing

I want to create a document with several pages and with one wpf window depicted on each page.

I managed to print one window using PrintDialog and PrintVisual. However this seem to only work with one single page? Any ideas how I can build a document with several pages and print the complete set.

Can I insert that visual (referred in code) and insert it as a page in a document and print it after that?

Is approach really bad? Is there som other way to solve this problem?

```
      Sub Print (Dim ele As FrameWorkElement)
            Dim margin As Double = 30
            Dim titlePadding As Double = 10

            Dim printDlg As PrintDialog = New PrintDialog()
            printDlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
            If (printDlg.ShowDialog() <> True) Then Return

            Dim formattedText As FormattedText = New FormattedText(Name, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                                                            FlowDirection.LeftToRight, New Typeface("Verdana"), 25, Brushes.Black)

            formattedText.MaxTextWidth = printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth

            Dim scale As Double = Math.Min(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth / (ele.ActualWidth + (Margin * 2)),
                                    (printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight - (formattedText.Height + titlePadding)) / (ele.ActualHeight + (Margin * 2)))

            Dim visual As DrawingVisual = New DrawingVisual()
            Using context As DrawingContext = visual.RenderOpen()

                Dim brush As VisualBrush = New VisualBrush(ele)
                context.DrawRectangle(brush, Nothing, New Rect(New Point(margin, margin + formattedText.Height + titlePadding),
                                                            New Size(ele.ActualWidth, ele.ActualHeight)))

                context.DrawText(formattedText, New Point(margin, margin))
            End Using
            visual.Transform = New ScaleTransform(scale, scale)
            printDlg.PrintVisual(visual, "")
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to create a `FixedDocument` with multiple `FixedPages`.

**Example:**

How to create a new document and single page.

```cs
var pageSize = new Size(8.26 * 96, 11.69 * 96); // A4 page, at 96 dpi
var document = new FixedDocument();
document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = pageSize;

// Create FixedPage
var fixedPage = new FixedPage();
fixedPage.Width = pageSize.Width;
fixedPage.Height = pageSize.Height;
// Add visual, measure/arrange page.
fixedPage.Children.Add((UIElement)visual);
fixedPage.Measure(pageSize);
fixedPage.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(), pageSize));
fixedPage.UpdateLayout();

// Add page to document
var pageContent = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
document.Pages.Add(pageContent);

// Send to the printer.
var pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "My Document");
```

Written in C#, however you should be able to convert to VB.

HTH,

Comment: What is `internalPage` supposed to reference?

Comment: @MichaelBromley, I have updated the sample. It was a copy/paste error, `internalPage` should have been `fixedPage`.

Comment: Ah, I guessed so. I managed to use your code anyway (figuring out the error for myself), so thanks a lot! Saved me a lot of time pursuing much more complex solutions.

Comment: @MichaelBromley. You're welcome. It took me a lot of work/investigation when I first did this work a few years ago.

Comment: Hi @Dennis , I have just copy/pasted the ninth row the word visual(fixedPage.Children.Add((UIElement)visual)) is not recognized in the visual studio can you help me please

Comment: `visual` is something you want to add to the page. See the original question where they create `new DrawingVisual()` - you want to do the same.