# How to print more pages document if it exceeds page size using PrintVisual

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

Currently I am able to print a single page scaled correctly to fit the user control that I am printing. However, the size of the user control exceeds the page size and I need it to print another page with the remaining part of the user control. Any Ideas how to go about this? I've looked at printing fixed documents or dumping the visual to a bitmap and cutting it up.

```
 private void Print( Visual v )
        {

            System.Windows.FrameworkElement e = v as System.Windows.FrameworkElement;
            if( e == null )
                return;

            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            if( pd.ShowDialog() == true )
            {
                //store original scale
                Transform originalScale = e.LayoutTransform;
                //get selected printer capabilities
                System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = pd.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities( pd.PrintTicket );

                //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
                double scaley = Math.Min( capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / e.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                               e.ActualHeight );

                double scalex = Math.Max( capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / e.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                              e.ActualHeight );
                //Transform the Visual to scale
                e.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform( 0.2823293807641634 + 0.2498215560314061, 0.2823293807641634 + 0.2498215560314061 );

                //get the size of the printer page
                System.Windows.Size sz = new System.Windows.Size( capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight );

                //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
                e.Measure( sz );
                e.Arrange( new System.Windows.Rect( new System.Windows.Point( capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight ), sz ) );

                //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
                pd.PrintVisual( v, "My Print" );


                //apply the original transform.
                e.LayoutTransform = originalScale;
            }
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
  Print( this.gdOuterReport );
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138948/how-to-print-multiple-wpf-pages-in-one-document